# Why is ajax call to iis hosted wcf service still returning data when the site hosting the service is down?

Tags: wcf, windows-desktop-gadgets

I'm developing a windows sidebar gadget that calls out to a wcf service via a javascript xmlhttprequest. If you stop the iis site hosting the service, shouldn't all calls to that service from the client return a 404 or something similar? The gadget and wcf service are running on separate machines. When I stop the iis site hosting the service and then drag the gadget from the gallery on to the sidebar, It is still populating correctly with data returned from the web service. However pasting the url for the service method into the browser correctly returns a 404. I must be missing something here.

I'm trying to reproduce a scenario where the gadget cannot reach the service so that I can test my xmlhttprequest error listener code.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it using cached results from a previous request?

Comment: I'm not sure how can I verify that? I'm using vs debugger attaching to the gadget process - I can see the data returned from the xmlhttprequest in the response text

Comment: John you were right, I had a browser window open. When I deleted all of the cookies, etc. and closed the window, I reloaded the gadget. The expected 404 was thrown. I would still like to understand why I was still getting a status of 200 back when the site was down.